# pandas.Series.unique() gives different result to np.unique() when analysing strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a method to voxelise a large dataset that creates a binary value (12 bytes) for all unique voxels, I can then take a subset using `df.isin()` to query.

I was using the `pandas.Series.unique()` as an input to this query but was getting strange results so tried `np.unique()` and it worked. My question why do I get different results?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import struct

def voxel(tmp):

    binarize = lambda x: struct.pack('i', int((x * 100) / 5))

    tmp.loc[:, 'xb'] = tmp.x.apply(binarize)
    tmp.loc[:, 'yb'] = tmp.y.apply(binarize)
    tmp.loc[:, 'zb'] = tmp.z.apply(binarize)
    tmp.loc[:, 'B'] = tmp.xb + tmp.yb + tmp.zb

    return tmp

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 100),
                      np.arange(0, 100),
                      np.arange(0, 100))

grid = pd.DataFrame(data=np.vstack([X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Z.flatten()]).T, 
                    columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

grid = voxel(grid)

print 'numpy:', len(np.unique(grid.B)), 'pandas:', len(grid.B.unique())
```

Which produces

```
numpy:100000 pandas:99
```

I have tested this using Pandas 0.23.0 with Python 2.7.14 on RHEL 7.5.1804 and on my MacBook

Comment: I just run your code in Python 3.6.7 (Anaconda, Windows) with NumPy 1.15.4 and Pandas 0.23.4 and got the answer `numpy: 1000000 pandas: 1000000`.